# Проблемы с установкой apk из кэша

Tags: android

Всем привет! Пытаюсь скачать на кэш приложения apk файл, и затем установить его. Скачать, то я скачиваю, но установить не могу. Подскажите кто знает в чём здесь может быть проблема? Тестирую на эмуляторе, а не на реальном устройстве. Вот код:

```
URL url = new URL("Путь до файла");
//Скачиваем файл
HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
c.setRequestMethod("GET");
c.setDoOutput(true);
c.connect();

String PATH = getCacheDir();

File file = new File(PATH);
File outputFile = new File(file, "/app.apk");
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);

InputStream is = c.getInputStream();

byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
int len1 = 0;
while ((len1 = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
    fos.write(buffer, 0, len1);
}
fos.close();
is.close();

//Устанавливаем файл

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(getCacheDir() + "/app.apk")),"application/vnd.android.package-archive");
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent); //Когда пытаюсь установить файл возникает ошибка "Parse error — there is a problem parcing the package"
```

Comment: @RomkaKraynov, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Comment: А при обычной установке apk нормально ставиться?

Comment: Фишка в том что когда я скачиваю не на кэш приложения а на память телефона.То проблем не возникает.

Comment: добавьте тэгов

Comment: Каких тэгов?

Comment: Попробуйте из кэша записать файл на память и установить его. Наверняка при записи в кэш глюки пошли

Comment: пробовал писать не только на кэш, но и на другие места. Нифига не получаеться.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сталкивался с такой же проблемой. Попробуйте заменить

```
String PATH = getCacheDir();    
File file = new File(PATH);
File outputFile = new File(file, "/app.apk");
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
```

на

```
OutputStream output = mContext.openFileOutput(apk_name, Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE | Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);
```

для дальнейшего доступа к файлу используйте

```
 File file = new File(mContext.getFilesDir(), apk_name);
```

Comment: Нет так не получается потому что Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE|Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE устарели.

Comment: не страшно, не думаю что их убирут в даже в андроиде 7+

Comment: просто в api 17 они уже не используються

Comment: это просто deprecated еще ничего не значит, есть куча функций и методов, которые устарели еще во второй версии Java, а уже 8я вышла и они до сих пор там есть :)

Comment: всё понятно.

Comment: Что-то я попробовал это:
OutputStream output = mContext.openFileOutput(apk_name, Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE | Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);

и всё равно такая же беда(((((

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я понимаю, проблема в том, что инсталлятор не имеет достаточных прав на чтение из каталога кэша. Надо скопировать APK из кэша на карту памяти и уже на него напустить инсталлятор (Intent инсталляции).

Comment: да если бы все так было хорошо :) дело в том, что я встречал устройства, которые не имеют external storage и копировать некуда. У меня стояла точно такая же задача, все было хорошо, пока не попался плохой девайс, пришлось переписывать. :(

Comment: Правильно думайте, но как раз на карту памяти мне не надо скидывать. Потому что может оказаться что у пользователя на телефоне может не быть карты памяти.